# Make DOM changes manually, instead of relying on React's reconciliation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make a React component that wraps a complex rendering API. This API can render a plot into HTML+SVG and also provides a function to update the plot with new data. The update function is optimized and avoids creating or changing elements it doesn't need (just like React's reconciliation algorithm).

How do I wrap such a plot in React? I could just render it in the `render()` function, but I would really like to use the library's update code. Is there any way to override React's rendering and do the DOM manipulations to update on my own?

I've seen code override `shouldComponentUpdate` to return `false`, such as [here](https://gist.github.com/llamaluvr/283649a08b9db30f58456765cf0f0aee). That would probably work, but the documentation says

> Note that in the future React may treat `shouldComponentUpdate()` as a hint rather than a strict directive, and returning `false` may still result in a re-rendering of the component.

Also, I'm not sure where I should react to state changes and do the DOM manipulation - in `shouldComponentUpdate` or `setState`?

I know this is a bit against the purpose of using React, but I think it is still useful. I can place my component inside other components, they don't have to know about the implementation details, and so on.

---

For the curious, the plotting library I'm using is [JSROOT](https://github.com/linev/jsroot/).

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar with NVD3 (also a chart library). And my approach was:

- Inside render, just leave a svg there with a unique ID
- Call a function at ComponentDidMount or other external function that calls your chart library and make things by directly changing the DOM.

Example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.addGraph(this.props)
  }

render() {
    const { id, height } = this.props
    return (
      <div className={ styles.graph } ref="graphDiv">
        <svg
          id={`Graph-${id}` }
          style={ { height } }
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

addGraph function:

```
export default function addGraph({ data, height, width }) {
  const d3 = require('d3')
  const nv = require('nvd3')

 nv.addGraph(() => {
    const chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
      .x(d => d[0])
      .y(d => d[1])
      .height(height)

 d3.select('#' + 'Graph' + '-' + id)
      .datum(data)
      .call(chart)

 return chart
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good! How do you handle updates? Do you put the new data in props or state, or do you do it outside of React?

Comment: I prefer put new data in props, and than remove and add the graph again with the new Data, or just update him